# JQuery - end date less than start date

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to fix this problem I'm having. I have to input tags, one is for Training beginning date and other is for training ending date. What i am trying to do is create a jQuery function that will prevent user from selecting an end date to be less than the start date and vice versa.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Training beggining date:</label>
    <input id="StartDate" style="margin-left: 10px;" size="16" type="text"/>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Training completion date:</label>
    <input id="EndDate" style="margin-left: 10px;" size="16" type="text"/>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419804/restrict-date-in-jquery-datepicker-based-on-another-datepicker-or-textbox and a lot of other similar solutions that I have found on the net but nothing works. It doesn't even register my changes. It's always the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution

```
var startDate = new Date('01/01/2012');
var FromEndDate = new Date();
var ToEndDate = new Date();
ToEndDate.setDate(ToEndDate.getDate() + 365);

$('.from_date').datepicker({
weekStart: 1,
startDate: '01/01/2012',
endDate: FromEndDate,
autoclose: true
})
.on('changeDate', function (selected) {
        startDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
        startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate(new Date(selected.date.valueOf())));
        $('.to_date').datepicker('setStartDate', startDate);
    });
$('.to_date')
    .datepicker({
        weekStart: 1,
        startDate: startDate,
        endDate: ToEndDate,
        autoclose: true
    })
    .on('changeDate', function (selected) {
        FromEndDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
        FromEndDate.setDate(FromEndDate.getDate(new Date(selected.date.valueOf())));
        $('.from_date').datepicker('setEndDate', FromEndDate);
    });
```

Answer (score 9):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#StartDate").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
          $("#EndDate").datepicker("option","minDate", selected)
        }
    });
    $("#EndDate").datepicker({ 
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
           $("#StartDate").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected)
        }
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Here you have the same question with Jquery UI Datepicker [jQuery UI Picking a start and end date within range based on start date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016598/jquery-ui-picking-a-start-and-end-date-within-range-based-on-start-date) And a working example:

html

```
<input type="text" id="dt1">
<input type="text" id="dt2">
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#dt1").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
        minDate: 0,
        onSelect: function (date) {
            var dt2 = $('#dt2');
            var startDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            dt2.datepicker('setDate', minDate);
            startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 30);
            //sets dt2 maxDate to the last day of 30 days window
            dt2.datepicker('option', 'maxDate', startDate);
            dt2.datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
            $(this).datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
        }
    });
    $('#dt2').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy"
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PPSh3/7/

Hope that help

Comment: Its still gives me the same result. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 3):

Just expanding off fusions answer. this extension method works using the jQuery validate plugin. It will validate dates and numbers

```
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("greaterThan", 
    function(value, element, params) {

    if (!/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value))) {
        return new Date(value) > new Date($(params).val());
    }

    return isNaN(value) && isNaN($(params).val()) 
        || (Number(value) > Number($(params).val())); 
    },'Must be greater than {0}.');
```

To use it:

```
$("#EndDate").rules('add', { greaterThan: "#StartDate" });
```

Or

```
$("form").validate({
rules: {
    EndDate: { greaterThan: "#StartDate" }
}
});
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about how to implement the first function with how to use it ?

Answer (score 1):

Date picker has an option to validate start date and end date.

HTML

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#from").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        maxDate: '0',
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        jQuery( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
    jQuery("#to").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        maxDate: '0',
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        jQuery( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: great approach, worked for me, very functional an classy

Comment: found a defect on this one - when you do a couple of tests, and try to set a new 'from' date, it will get stuck on the last selected date

Answer (score 0):

> JQuery - end date less than start date 100% Work And Also Dynamically 
>   Date.

For Show Date With Today Date

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.bet_start').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    todayHighlight: true,
    startDate: '0d'
});
})</script>
```

For end date less than start date

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.bet_start').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    todayHighlight: true,
    startDate: '0d'
});
var startDate = new Date('18/09/2019');
var FromEndDate = new Date();
var ToEndDate = new Date();
ToEndDate.setDate(ToEndDate.getDate() + 365);

$('.bet_start').datepicker({
    weekStart: 1,
    startDate: '18/09/2019',
    endDate: FromEndDate,
    autoclose: true
})
    .on('changeDate', function (selected) {
        startDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
        startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate(new Date(selected.date.valueOf())));
        $('.bet_end').datepicker('setStartDate', startDate);
    });
$('.bet_end')
    .datepicker({
        weekStart: 1,
        startDate: startDate,
        endDate: ToEndDate,
        autoclose: true
    })
    .on('changeDate', function (selected) {
        FromEndDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
        FromEndDate.setDate(FromEndDate.getDate(new Date(selected.date.valueOf())));
        $('.bet_start').datepicker('setEndDate', FromEndDate);
    });

});</script>
```