# DatePicker Start Date and Finish Date Validation without plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, datepicker

Using Asp.Net MVC 4 with JqueryUI.

I have 2 textboxes which provide me datepickers. I need validation for; start date can be equal to finish date and finish date can not be less from start date.

Datepicker script code;

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".date").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
    });

</script>
```

My textboxes:

```
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate, "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", new { @class = "date", @id="dt1" }) </td>

<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FinishDate, "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", new { @class = "date", @id="dt2" }) </td>
```

[I found this code from this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19317678/jquery-end-date-less-than-start-date). But i can't get validation. I cant figure out what's the problem. All helps will be appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#dt1").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
    minDate: 0,
    onSelect: function (date) {
        var dt2 = $('#dt2');
        var startDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        dt2.datepicker('setDate', minDate);
        startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 30);
        //sets dt2 maxDate to the last day of 30 days window
        dt2.datepicker('option', 'maxDate', startDate);
        dt2.datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
        $(this).datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
    }
});
$('#dt2').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-M-yy"
});
```

});

[JQuery - end date less than start date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19317678/jquery-end-date-less-than-start-date)

Comment: When do you want to show the validation of both dates are equal? I mean when you check the dates or when you click a submit

Comment: thank you for your answer.

I need something like this. Please check this link out:
http://jsfiddle.net/PPSh3/7/

Answer (score 1):

I think this may helps you, when you changes one of the datepickers will show an error if both are different. and also se the `isValid` variable to false too stop it from being able to submit

```
<script>
    var isValid=true;
    $(function () {
        $(".date").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            onSelect: function() {
                var date1 = $("#dt1").datepicker('getDate');
                var date2 = $("#dt2").datepicker('getDate');
                if (date1.getDate() === date2.getDate() && 
                    date1.getMonth() === date2.getMonth() &&
                    date1.getFullYear() === date2.getFullYear())
                {
                     isValid=false;
                     //ALERT error 
                }
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Ok it solved.

Here is the different solution if someone needs

http://jsfiddle.net/jquerybyexample/CkfDP/