# How to prevent onselect date filling in the field after the blur function

Tags: jquery, datepicker, blur

I have a blur function to check two dates by datepicker. If the end date is before the begin date, it will alert an error and the selected date could not be filled in the input field. Firstly trigger blur event:

```
...date picker
onSelect: function() {
    this.focus();

},
onClose: function() {
    this.blur();
}
```

...validate part

```
jQuery("#p_stdy_edate").blur(function() {
    var stdy_bdate = jQuery("#p_stdy_sdate").val();
    var stdy_edate = jQuery("#p_stdy_edate").val();
    if (stdy_edate < stdy_bdate) {
        alert("End date should be later than begin date");    
    }

});
```

But when I select an invalid end date(the end date input box has a default date), the invalid date is filled into input field after showing the alert. How to fix it?

Comment: More elegant solution to your problem might be not allowing user to select any invalid date. You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19317678/jquery-end-date-less-than-start-date).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right after you display the alert, you can force the value of edate to the one you had prior to the invalid entry; for example:

```
jQuery("#p_stdy_edate").blur(function() {
    var stdy_bdate = jQuery("#p_stdy_sdate").val();
    var stdy_edate = jQuery("#p_stdy_edate").val();
    if (stdy_edate < stdy_bdate) {
        alert("End date should be later than begin date"); 
        $("#p_stdy_edate").val("Please Select Ending Date");
    }
});
```

That would be if "Please Select Ending Date" is youe default value, you can of course modify it; I would also use on focusout as the event instead of blur (blur can cause false-positives in my experience when using it in this fashion); using focusout and validating could possibly work much better (esp. if your setting values dynamically, you'd want the user's focus to trigger the validation not when you programmatically make a value change).

-- Edit; made it even easier with change event; please test the code below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" />

      <title>Ilan's Test</title>
   </head>
   <body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-12'>
            <div class="form-group">
                Start Date : <input id="sdate" class="form-control" type="text" /><br />
                End Date : <input id="edate" class="form-control" type="text" /><br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){

            $('#sdate').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                altField: '#thealtdate',
                altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
            });

            $('#edate').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                altField: '#thealtdate',
                altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
            });

            $('#edate').on('change',function () {
                var sdate = $('#sdate').val();
                var edate = $('#edate').val();
                var diff = new Date(new Date(edate) - new Date(sdate));
                var days = diff/1000/60/60/24;
                if(days < 0){
                    alert("Sorry! You must pick an end date that is greater!");
                    $('#edate').val('');    
                } else {
                    alert ("This date range is good! Your start date and end dates are " + days + " days apart!");
                }           
                return false;
            });

        });
        </script>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you give me a simple demo about using focusout to handle date range checking? Thanks

Comment: Awesome! Welcome :)

Comment: By the way, is the "return false" necessary in the function? I tried without that, it works fine also.

Comment: Nope not needed, just a habit of mine to include it heh